# iOS File Security

Tags: ios, file, security

Is that possible to access files when they have NSFileProtectionNone flag? As I right understand, those features allow only to encrypt a file, but not to gain the access to it. Does iOS security model inherit Linux capabilities by limiting the access to app's internal directory (like /data/data/app_name/ in Android which is not accessible for non-app users)?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation. This is a lengthy and complicated subject that you cannot just answer in a few sentences. But in principle, an app can only access its own data; multiple apps created by the same developer can share data if the developer chooses to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. See documentation:

> Because it is in a sandbox, an app is generally prohibited from
>   accessing or creating files outside its containers. One exception to
>   this rule occurs when an app uses public system interfaces to access
>   things such as the user’s contacts or music. [...]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Then why do we need file encryption and those flags? If nobody besides the app can access it, we don't need to encrypt it

Comment: To make sure that any hacker cannot access it. Or someone removing the flash drive from your phone.

Comment: Well, i would say, no system is perfect secure. You can attack every system in such a way to get the informations you want. Here for example, you can get the backup of a device an extract the files. If the files are encrypted they are useless

Comment: I understand now, thanks. So the Android system is more vulnerable because it allows to change filesystem permissions and get the access to files to any apps?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html says "no application, [...], has permission to [...] reading or writing another application's files". But reading and writing any file on external storage isn't restricted in the way iOS does.